# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable (diferential equation)

Tags: python, differential-equations

```
def funk(m,t):
    return [m[0], -m[0]+m[1]*np.sin(t)]
zac_pogoji = [15, 10, 13]
h = 0.1
solver = ode(funk).set_initial_value(zac_pogoji)

zac = [zac_pogoji]
sprem = [0]

while solver.t < 5:
    solver.integrate(solver.t + h)
    zac.append(solver.y)
    sprem.append(solver.t)

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm trying to numericly solve differential equation: z(y)*sin(y) = z'''(y)+z'(y) and somehow i just can't get to solve it. Should i use some other way of solving 3rd order diff.eq?

Comment: Your code indentation is not proper.

Comment: I'm new to python and it's really hard for me to understand what i'm doing wrong in the first place.

Comment: Please try using [this tool](https://github.com/alexmojaki/askso) to help you write a clearer question.

Comment: Please describe your specific problem. "i just can't get to solve it" just does not tell us anything.